# Ruby: Ordered array and add to array at next number if number exists

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if anyone new of an easy way to organize an array by numbers but if the number already exists push it to the next number that doesn't exist I was thinking of just creating a multi-dimensional ordered array where if numbers clash (such as 2 pages having 1) then the first would be [1][1] and the second would be [1][2] but is there a better way to handle this?

Edit; an example:

```
page1 -> sets order to 1
page2 -> sets order to 1
page3 -> sets order to 2
```

Normally I would go through and YAML read the pages configurations and get the order and then use that number and set `_site.sidebar[_config["order"]]` but in this case it would clash and it wouldn't add it. So I'm looking for a way to allow for user mistakes but preserve order keeping the first found as one but if one exists shift the array down and put the second 1 as two.

Comment: I can't understand you. Can you show an example?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, let's say you have arrays [1][2][3], [4][1][5] and [1][2][1], you would want the resulting order to be [1][2][1], [1][2][3] and [4][1][5]. Is that correct?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you're implementing a hashtable, and using 'number' as hash. There are all kinds of algorithms for that, just look for hashtable algorithms.

Comment: From spec looks like hashtable with number will do a job

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final snippet on how I implemented what I was asking about, just in case somebody else stumbles upon this thread looking for the same sort of thing.  I basically just wanted to preserve the order, in my actual application of the code I used a normal multi-dimensional array since "order" was pulled from YAML front so it is it's own variable.

```
data = []
demo = {
  "page_1" => {
    "order" => 1,
    "data" => "Hello World 1"
  },
  "page_2" => {
    "order" => 2,
    "data" => "Hello World 2"
  },
  "page_3" => {
    "order" => 1,
    "data" => "Hello World 3"
  },
  "page_4" => {
    "order" => "a",
    "data" => "Hello World 4"
  }
}

demo.each |key, page|
  local_data = page["data"]
  order      = page["order"].to_i.floor

  data[order] ||= []
  data[order] << local_data

}
puts data.flatten.join(" ").strip
```